# Finding condition on $k$ so that $f:\mathbb{R^{+}}\mapsto [2,\infty]$, $f(x)=x^2+kx+k$ is surjective

Tags: calculus, functions

I have the following question that simply asks to find the set of values of $k$, so that the function $f:\mathbb{R^{+}}\mapsto [2,\infty]$ given by $f(x)=x^2+kx+k$ is surjective.

So two possible cases arise, when vertex of the parabola are to the left and right of the $y$-axis, which are equivalent to $k$ being positive or negative. In the case when $k\gt0$, then as $x\to 0^{+}$, $f(0^{+})=k\to 2^{+}$, so $k\in(2,\infty)$. And when $k\lt 0$, the minima is $(-k/2,2)$, and solving for $k$ gives imaginary roots.

Now it looks like $k\in(2,\infty)$ which implies $f(x)\in(2,\infty)\forall x\in\mathbb{R^{+}}$. But clearly this is not the same as the co-domain of the function. Shouldn't the answer be $\not\exists k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is surjective? So why is this answer taken to be correct as is? Thanks

**Note**: The notation $\mathbb{R^{+}}$ has been used for representing $x |x\in\mathbb{R}\cap x\gt0$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Definition**: $f$ is surjective iff for all $y\in[2, \infty]$ there exists at least one $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $f(x) = y$.

---

First let's see what happens if we define $\mathbb{R}^+ = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x \geq 0\}$. Now assume $k<2$, this would imply 
$$f(0) = 0^2 + 0 k + k = k < 2,$$
which means that $f$ no longer maps to $[2, \infty)$. As we assumed $f: \mathbb{R}^+ \mapsto [2, \infty)$ then $k$ must be larger or equal to $2$.

Now suppose $k > 2$, then 
$$f(x) = x^2 + k x + k \geq k > 2
$$ 
which means for $y = 2$ there exists no $x$ such that $f(x) = y$. So $f$ cannot be surjective.

We are left with the case that $k=2$,
$$
f_0(x) = x^2 + 2x + 2 = (x+1)^2 + 1.
$$
Is $f_0$ surjective? For all $y\in[2, \infty]$ we can let $x = \sqrt{y - 1} - 1$ (which is always defined as $y \geq 2$), such that 
$$f_0(\sqrt{y -1} -1) = (\sqrt{y-1}-1 + 1)^2 + 1 = y
$$

---

Now instead define $\mathbb{R}^+ = \{x\in \mathbb{R}: x > 0\}$. We would like $f$ to map $(0, \infty)$ to $[2, \infty)$. This requires
$$
\underset{\mathbb{R}^+}{\min} f(x) = 2
$$
As $f$ is differentiable this is attained for $x = -k/2$,
$$
f(-k/2) = \frac{k^2}{4} - \frac{k^2}{2} + k = -\frac{k^2}{2} + k
$$
The solutions to 
$$
-\frac{k^2}{2} + k = 2
$$
are found for $k = 1 \pm i \sqrt{3}$. But inserting either of these yields
$$
f(1) = 1 + 2 \pm 2 i \sqrt{3}
$$
and our function is no longer mapping to $[2, \infty]$ but rather to the complex plane. In summary I agree with you.

Comment: For the case $k=2$. $f(x)=(x+1)^{2}+1\gt2 \forall x\in\mathbb{R^{+}}$. So it is not surjective for any $k\in\mathbb{R}$. What do you conclude with the $k=2$ case?

Comment: I assumed 
$$\mathbb{R}^+  = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x \geq 0\}.$$
If you intended
$$\mathbb{R}^+ = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x > 0\},$$
then you are correct, there exists no $k$.

Comment: Ahh. I will be deleting the comment in question as I think it might confuse future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The function cannot be surjective since $\text{Dom}f-[2,+\infty]$ is not empty.

Comment: That is true for a bijective function. For a surjective function, the number of elements in the co-domain can be less than or equal to the number of elements in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

0) $f(x)=x^2+kx+k \ge 2$, $x \in [2,\infty)$.

$f(0)=k \ge 2$;

1) Assume $k >2$: $f(0)>2$.

$f(x)=x^2+kx +k$ is strictly increasing for $x \in [0,\infty)$,

since $x^2$, $kx$ are strictly increasing.

For $x >0:$ $f(x)>f(0) >2$, i.e. $f$ is not surjective (There is no $x \in [0,\infty)$ s.t. $f(x)=2$)

2) Remains $k=2$.

$f(x)=x^2+2x+2= (x+1)^2+1$;

$f$ continuos, $f(0)=2$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x)=\infty$, hence surjective.